# Inserting user records into MYSQL table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create a register page for users to register new accounts. 
I am using signup.jsp page with the register form
Which is then connected to RegisterServlet.java  (gets form parameters and inserts parameters into database after connecting to DBConnection.java)
DBConnection contains the try{} of connecting to the mysql database.

I have tried multiple ways of registering a user, but the users information never inserts into database.

signup.jsp:

```
<form action="RegisterServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" id="pass2" name="pass2" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <%=(request.getAttribute("errMessage") == null) ? ""
                                                : request.getAttribute("errMessage")%>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="pull-left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button></div>
                                     </form>
```

RegisterServlet.java:

```
@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RegisterServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     try
        {
        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
        Connection con = db.getCon();


            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into user (fname, lname, username, password)values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+username+"','"+password+"')");
            System.out.println("data inserted sucessfully");
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       


    }

}
```

DBConnection.java

```
public class DBConnection {

    public Connection con;

    public Connection getCon(){
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cultureexchange", "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
        }
}
```

Sql user table:

```
fname    lname    username    password
varchar  varchar  varchar     varchar
```

My login.jsp works so the connection to database must work, 
appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Fix the SQL injection. Don't store passwords as plain text . After fixing those, what web response do you get? What exception do you get? Or error log?

Comment: try adding a `commit`

Comment: did you add **mysql-j-connector** to your project ?

Comment: @Swati no i did not, would you mind explaining what that is?

Comment: Check for more details here ->https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-java-connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Changing these line

```
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into user (fname, lname, username, password)values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+username+"','"+password+"')");
```

to

```
 PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user (fname, lname, username, password)values(?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, fname);
            ps.setString(2, lname);
            ps.setString(3, username);
            ps.setString(4, password);
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

And make sure that you have **mysql-j-connector** in your **lib** folder under `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Followed this tutorial for adding mysql-j-connector : http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Tutorial:_Accessing_a_MySql_database_in_Java_(Eclipse)           and edited the preparedstatement as you explained but still when I click register the page just refreshes and no user info is placed in database...

Comment: no sir, I am not getting any error, this is why I am confused.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your database?

Comment: @james Also give a screenshot of your project structure please

Comment: Caused by an import statement that was not being used.

Comment: Can you just remove `onsubmit="return validate()"` from html page and try ?

Comment: Removed onsubmit function still doesn't work, but <form> tag has yellow underline saying invalid location of tag <form> .

Comment: I think this post call is not entering in your post method. Print something inside post method in servlet and check whether call is entering or not

Comment: Yes it seems to not be entering the post method, i tried just System.out.println("Hello") and nothing was outputted.

Comment: That means your servlet hasn't registered

Comment: What does it mean that my servlet has not registered?

Comment: Post your web.xml please

Comment: I usually just use annotation in the servlet and it works @WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")    but here is my web.xml:  https://imgur.com/5NUchsW

Comment: Adding <servlet-mapping> to web.xml file gives error when i run it: Starting Tomcat v8.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem.

Comment: Found the issue was with form tag within signup.jsp, thank you for your help! Without you telling me the problem was that post was not being sent to servlet I would have had a much harder time figuring it out. Blessings to you sir